# Validate an integer with Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to validate a text field in Groovy.

My problem is the second line, where I try to check if the string is a number:

```
println("Valor del año: " + newValue.toString());
println("Valor true/false añoEntero: " + newValue.toString().isNumber());
```

The output printed is:

```
Jun 12, 2014 11:17:46 AM UTC    Valor del año: 1995
Jun 12, 2014 11:17:46 AM UTC    JBO-25150: The method isNumber on class java.lang.String is not permitted.
```

Could you help me with the correct method in Groovy to validate an integer?

Regards,

María

Comment: Which version of Groovy?

Comment: @dmahapatro I'm new with Groovy and I don´t know how to check the version. I work with Oracle Sales Cloud R8  and this application uses Groovy in some validation field

Comment: `groovy -version` is the command to run in shell/cmd if the classpath and path is set properly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.isInteger()`, e.g.

```
assert '33'.isInteger()
assert 'assa'.isInteger() == false
assert '44.3'.isInteger() == false
```

Comment: Hi @Dónal, I´ve tried next lines but I get the same error. First and second println return a correct value, and the third one is wrong.

[pre][code]
println("Valor del año: " + newValue.toString());
println("Valor true/false añoEntero: " );
println("Valor true/false añoEntero: " + newValue.isNumber());

[pre][code]
Jun 12, 2014 01:53:11 PM UTC JBO-25150: The method isNumber on class java.lang.String is not permitted.
Jun 12, 2014 01:53:11 PM UTC Valor true/false añoEntero:
Jun 12, 2014 01:53:11 PM UTC Valor del año: 2015

Comment: The reason you're getting this error is because you're calling `String.isNumber()` which doesn't exist.

Comment: It´s true... But I changed the method and the error persists...

println("Valor del año: " + newValue.toString());
println("Valor true/false añoEntero: " + newValue.isInteger());

Jun 12, 2014 04:04:32 PM UTC Valor del año: 2013
Jun 12, 2014 04:04:32 PM UTC JBO-25150: The method isInteger on class java.lang.String is not permitted.

Comment: `isNumber` does exist.

Comment: @dmahapatro judging by the error message, it seems that it doesn't exist in whatever version of Groovy OP Is using

Comment: Exactly according to my comment to OP. Based on that same version, `isInteger()` will be and is invalid as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be using an older version of Groovy ([older than 1.5](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isNumber%28%29)), which doesn't have the `isInteger` and `isNumber` methods.  You could just implement the check yourself:

```
Boolean isNumber(value) {
    try {
        new BigDecimal(value)

        return true
    } catch (MissingMethodException exception) {
        return false
    }
}
```

then call it with:

```
println("Valor del año: " + newValue.toString())
println("Valor true/false añoEntero: " + isInteger(newValue.toString()))
```

And some tests:

```
assert !isNumber('a')
assert isNumber('-4')
assert isNumber('3')
assert isNumber('1234.5')
```